# NodeJS REPL Variable-Assignment -- need help figuring out what's wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, command-line

I come from the python world & I'm trying to use the node-REPL on a windows machine to do some on-the-fly testing from the CLI.

Here's an issue I can't resolve:

```
> var foo = true;
undefined
> foo
true
> foo

> foo
> foo
true
> foo
true
> foo

> foo
true
```

My question is: How should I try to figure out what is going on??

Comment: What node version?

Comment: @mscdex -- node is v6.10.0

Comment: I wasn't able to duplicate it using node v6.10.0 on Windows 7 using cmd.exe.

Comment: The node REPL is also having issues for me. I have no idea what is causing it. Outpu is all over the place.

Comment: Looks like it was a Win 10 Memory leakage bug. Upgrading to a newer Node version fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in a newer version of v6.x, so try upgrading to the latest v6.x. [Here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12085) is the relevant node issue thread.

Comment: Thank you! This is a good reminder for me to check github issues first.

Also this tool was helpful for upgrading node quickly: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows.